# Why does adding "clear:both;" after a row of floated items clears issues with content push-overs?

Tags: html, css, css-float

When I was building a 2 columns layout and having the first items of each row floated to left, I was faced with an issue. If the element's text was much bigger than intended, the rows would break, items being pushed down, so instead of it looking like this:

[image: How the layout should look]

it looks like this:

[image: How it looks without clear: both;]

The code being:

```
<ul class="layout">
<li>
    <article>
        <div class="thumb">
            <img class="img" alt="" src="">
        </div>
        <div class="post-info">
            <h3>Hey there! You should make me bigger to break the layout.</h3>
            <p>Some text here...</p>
        </div>
    </article>
</li>
<li>
    <article>
        <div class="thumb">
            <img class="img" alt="" src="">
        </div>
        <div class="post-info">
            <h3>Hey there! You should make me bigger to break the layout.</h3>
            <p>Some text here...</p>
        </div>
    </article>
</li>
<li>
    <article>
        <div class="thumb">
            <img class="img" alt="" src="">
        </div>
        <div class="post-info">
            <h3>Hey there! You should make me bigger to break the layout.</h3>
            <p>Some text here...</p>
        </div>
    </article>
</li>
<li>
    <article>
        <div class="thumb">
            <img class="img" alt="" src="">
        </div>
        <div class="post-info">
            <h3>Hey there! You should make me bigger to break the layout.</h3>
            <p>Some text here...</p>
        </div>
    </article>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.layout {
    list-style: none;
}

.layout > li {
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 49%;
}

.layout > li:nth-child(odd) {
    margin-right: 1%;
    float: left;
}

.layout > li:nth-child(even) {
    margin-left: 1%;
    float: right;
}
```

Which works, but if we are to make the  longer, it'd break.

If we add this line:

```
.layout > li:nth-child(even) + li {
    clear: both;
}
```

It works just perfectly, no matter what I throw at it.

How come?

Comment: Would appreciate someone with reputation that could edit the images to embed.

Comment: adding `float` creates a new *block formatting context* which should be *cleared* to say that the context has ended... see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)

Comment: @kukkuz I understand! But how come I can still keep float: left and clear: both; on the same item and why exactly does it work if I clear every third (first of row) element?

Answer (score 0):

Just use only `float: left` for ALL elements in your case.

```css
.layout {
  list-style: none;
}
.layout>li {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
}

.layout>li:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.layout>li:nth-child(even) {
  margin-left: 1%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="layout">
  <li>
    <article>
      <div class="thumb">
        <img class="img" alt="" src="">
      </div>
      <div class="post-info">
        <h3>Hey there! You should make me bigger to break the layout.</h3>
        <p>Some text here...</p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </li>
  <li>
    <article>
      <div class="thumb">
        <img class="img" alt="" src="">
      </div>
      <div class="post-info">
        <h3>Hey there! You should make me bigger to break the layout.</h3>
        <p>Some text here...</p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </li>
  <li>
    <article>
      <div class="thumb">
        <img class="img" alt="" src="">
      </div>
      <div class="post-info">
        <h3>Hey there! You should make me bigger to break the layout.</h3>
        <p>Some text here...</p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </li>
  <li>
    <article>
      <div class="thumb">
        <img class="img" alt="" src="">
      </div>
      <div class="post-info">
        <h3>Hey there! You should make me bigger to break the layout.</h3>
        <p>Some text here...</p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Application of clear clears out the floats for current container which would have otherwise got applied due to preceding or inherited styles.

The only layout that is now applied to these elements are their own. That's why, it works as desired.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clear

For your layout, you float box 1 to left, then box2 to left. Then, you apply clear:both because you want to stop applying floats. Then, for the next row boxes, you apply floats again because you want to place them left.

*["When you apply clear:both to an element, it basically says "stop floating here" — this element and those after it in the source will not float, unless you apply a new float declaration to another element later on."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Floats)*